# C# XNA как узнать разрешение экрана/окна

Tags: c#, экран, xna

Нужно узнать текущие разрешение экрана(для полно экранного режима) и отдельно нужно узнать разрешение окна(оконный режим)
Есть какие либо стандартный функции в C# или в XNA для получения этой информации?

p.s. для оконного режима можно сделать возможность выбора разрешения окна, а эти значения можно вручную прописать как варианты, но для полноэкранного режима нужно знать возможные корректные разрешения: 
у моего экрана разрешение 1366х768
а у кого то 1920x1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;
GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
```

Или так:

```
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen
```

Ну, или так:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
```

Поля PrefferedBackBufferHeight и PrefferedBackBufferWidth.

Comment: Эти поля задают значения для приложения, а не позволяют узнать разрешение экрана